# Error upon sending and executing multiple test files

Tags: c#, path

I am writing an application which launches a tester (.cmd), so I am passing in the tests that have been entered into a listbox. This method works perfectly fine if there is one test entered, but if there is 2 or more, it give me the error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
>   occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified"

The `StartInfo.Filename` and the `currentTestFromListbox[i]` both look correct in the debugger.

Anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

I apologize that my code is confusing--im just a beginner.

```
public void executeCommandFiles()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int ii = 0;
        int numberOfTests = listboxTestsToRun.Items.Count;

    executeNextTest:
        var CurrentTestFromListbox = listboxTestsToRun.Items.Cast<String>().ToArray();
        string filenameMinusCMD = "error reassigning path value";
        int fileExtPos = CurrentTestFromListbox[i].LastIndexOf(".");

        if (fileExtPos >= 0)
        {
            filenameMinusCMD = CurrentTestFromListbox[i].Substring(0, fileExtPos);
        }

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.Arguments = @"pushd Y:\Tests\" + filenameMinusCMD + @"\" + CurrentTestFromListbox[i];
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"pushd Y:\Tests\" + filenameMinusCMD + @"\";
        startInfo.FileName = CurrentTestFromListbox[i];
        Process.Start(startInfo);

        //Wait for program to load before selecting main tab
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

        //Select MainMenu tab by sending a left arrow keypress
        SendKeys.Send("{LEFT}");

        i++;

        if (i < numberOfTests)
        {
            checkIfTestIsCurrentlyRunning:

            foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("nameOfProgramIAmTesting"))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

                    //if (ii > 150)

                    if (ii > 6) //test purposes only
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The current test (" + filenameMinusCMD + ") timed out at 5 minutes. The next test has been started.", "Test timed out",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    }

                    ii++;

                    goto checkIfTestIsCurrentlyRunning;
                }
                goto executeNextTest;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!
-Joel

Comment: http://xkcd.com/292/ Goto is bad, m'kay

Comment: Basically, there is a listbox with commands in it, and you want to run each of them sequentially, correct? Can you show us some examples of what the input in the list box looks like?

Comment: Also, the flow of this program is very... old fashioned. No offense, but there is no need for gotos or sleeps in this program. Once you get that example input up, I think I'll be able to re-factor to make it much easier to follow.

Comment: @Gray Correct.

The input to the listbox is the entire file path Y:\Tests\Testname\Testname.cmd (the folders of the test are always the exact same as the test name, just obviously without the .cmd), but is then trimmed to just the "testname.cmd" as shown in the 14th line of the example.

I'm not sure if that's enough info. If not, please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I just wanted to see some examples of what is in the listbox exactly. Like, does it look like "Testname.cmd -arg1 -arg2" or "Testname arg1 arg2" or is it just "testname.cmd" or "testname".

Comment: @Gray 

No arguments are passed in with the test name or anything. It really is just the testname.cmd being passed in/out of the listbox at this point.

And none taken! I realize I'm a very inefficient/sloppy coder. I'm just trying to get better.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see. I was confused because the arguments are being set. It looks like it just takes its own path as an argument though. ex: "Y:\tests\testname.cmd Y:\tests\testname.cmd" is the command you are executing. the argument is probably just ignored.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should've omitted that. I was playing around with different things trying to make it work. Originally I had the file name set to what the working directory is now PLUS the CurrentTestFromListbox[i], without the arguments or working directory.

Same error showed up as I am getting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code re-factored. The sleeps/gotos were really bothering me. I couldn't really test it, but I think it should work the same. Let me know if it doesn't work or you have any questions.

This assumes your listbox has content like this in it:

```
testname.cmd
test2.cmd
test3.exe
lasttest.bat
```

Here is my attempt:

```
public void executeCommandFiles()
{
    foreach (string test in listboxTestsToRun.Items)
    {
        //gets the directory name from given filename (filename without extension)
        //assumes that only the last '.' is for the extension. test.1.cmd => test.1
        string testName = test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf('.')); 

        //set up a FileInfo object so we can make sure the test exists gracefully.
        FileInfo testFile = new FileInfo(@"Y:\Tests\" + testName + "\\" + test);

        //check if it is a valid path
        if (testFile.Exists)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(testFile.FullName);
            //get the Process object so we can wait for it to finish.
            Process currentTest = Process.Start(startInfo);
            //wait 5 minutes then timeout (5m * 60s * 1000ms)
            bool completed = currentTest.WaitForExit(300000);
            if (!completed)
                MessageBox.Show("test timed out");
            //use this if you want to wait for the test to complete (indefinitely)
            //currentTest.WaitForExit();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + testFile.FullName + " was not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works wonderfully! Thank you

It's "timing out" after the test completes and everything is closed, but that's not a problem.

Much cleaner than mine as well... haha

Comment: Oh, I mixed that up. It returns true if it completes successfully. Updating it now.

Comment: You'll definitely want to look into some error handling and user input verification. Definitely look into using some try-catch blocks to make sure your program can handle issues like files getting deleted/file permissions/etc.

Comment: Okay, I'll be sure to do that. I'll need to learn how, but MSDN has been my best friend recently; it won't let me down.

Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Best of luck. You might want to look into a C# book. MSDN is great if you know what you are looking for, but a book can help give you the toolbox you need. In other words, msdn will show you how to use a goto when you search for it, but it wont talk about best practices and why using a goto in C# (very) rarely makes sense.